# List of lists of mixed types to numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have data imported from `csv` and they are stored in list of lists as:

```
data=[['1', ' 1.013831', ' 1.713332', ' 1.327002', ' 3.674446', ' 19.995361', ' 09:44:24', ' 2.659884'], ['2', ' 1.013862', ' 1.713164', ' 1.326761', ' 3.662183', ' 19.996973', ' 09:49:27', ' 2.668791'], ['3', ' 1.013817', ' 1.712084', ' 1.326192', ' 3.658077', ' 19.997608', ' 09:54:27', ' 2.671786']]
```

I want to get a `numpy` array so that I can actually use proper slicing (I don't want `pandas` or anything else, just plain old `numpy` array with appropriate data types - not object).

So I tried the obvious:

```
arr=np.array(data,dtype='i4,f4,f4,f4,f4,f4,U8,f4')
```

only to get:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' 1.013831'
```

This suggests that `numpy` treats rows as columns and columns as rows. What to do? I also tried to input instead of `data` `list(map(tuple,data))` which gives and error that `map object is not callable` and I tried:

```
arr=np.asarray(tuple(map(tuple,data)),dtype='i4,f4,f4,f4,f4,f4,U8,f4')
```

giving

```
ValueError: could not assign tuple of length 20 to structure with 8 fields.
```

Note the original number of rows in my case is 20.

So how do i get data from `csv` into `numpy` array where I want to specify what each column data type is?

Comment: Did you try `arr.T` to get the transpose and then setting the dtypes?

Comment: @SurajShourie Do you mean: `arr=np.asarray(data); arr2=arr.T; arr3=np.array(arr2,dtype='i4,f4,f4,f4,f4,f4,U8,f4')`? If so, this has the same issue. I am quite confused now. because in the code `arr[:,0]` correctly slices the first column so it should not be transposed. maybe the specification of `dtype` is not correct?

Comment: NumPy arrays have a single dtype. The advantage of `pd.DataFrame` is to have mixed data types in a single variable. I think you need pandas for this

Comment: @SurajShourie the last example at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asanyarray.html suggests otherwise, they have mixed columns of integers and floats.

Comment: It is a hack(ish) for numpy. If you notice they pass a single column, they pass it as a tuple. If you check the shape it will be one column only and you won't be able to do any matrix calculations that you want to do

Comment: If you want to make this work you'll have to change your data structure from list of list to list of tuples maybe

Comment: With that dtype, you need a list of 8 element tuples., pairing up the data tuple elements with the dtype terms.  If you still have cvs text, loading with genfromtxt might be easier.

Comment: the conversion to tuples can written as a list comprehension, `[tuple(row] for row in data]`

Answer (score 1):

From the example in the documentation, this works

```
np.array(list(map(tuple, data)), dtype='i4,f4,f4,f4,f4,f4,U8,f4')
```

Output:

```
array([(1, 1.013831, 1.713332, 1.327002, 3.674446, 19.995361, ' 09:44:2', 2.659884),
       (2, 1.013862, 1.713164, 1.326761, 3.662183, 19.996973, ' 09:49:2', 2.668791),
       (3, 1.013817, 1.712084, 1.326192, 3.658077, 19.997608, ' 09:54:2', 2.671786)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f4'), ('f4', '<f4'), ('f5', '<f4'), ('f6', '<U8'), ('f7', '<f4')])
f
1
```

Comment: How did you make this work? I am getting `TypeError: 'map' object is not callable`

Comment: you might have overriden `map` function with a variable, do `del map` and then it should work

Comment: @SurajShourie I had to exit completely from terminal and go back and now it solves the issue.

Comment: I have removed the answer mark as the above approach converts this to a one dimensional array: `print(arr.shape)` gives `(3,)` But if I remove the `dtype` statement, correct 2 dimensional array is generated. So how does one correctly specify the `dtype` for multidimensional arrays.